# Unity web player can't load picture by reloading on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, web, connection, unity-game-engine

I would like to create web application by using Unity web player.
The application is communicate to server by using webSocket-sharp,and background picture of title is loaded from server.

I'm about complete the application, however, when I reload the application, it failed, the picture isn't showed.
The phenomenon is only Mac(I tried safari, chrome). It didn't occur on Windows.

As far as I searched, "close" function(webSocket-sharp function) is immediately called after "open" function(webSocket-sharp function).

I can't solve the problem, could you tell me the reason?

thank you.

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I also met same problem. When reload or close the chrome/firefox/safari then open them again to reload the webplayer, the webplayer shall close the connection when it firstly uses the socket. I dump the chrome Helper EH(I think this guy manages webplayer plugin), it seems that the mono is waiting for some semaphore. If the chrome Helper EH is forced to quit, the webplayer becomes available again, the socket works. The case never gonna happen in Windows or Linux. It could be a webplayer plugin issue in mac. I try to figure out what is the semaphore the mono waiting for. If I can release the semaphore in code, the issue could be fixed. Util now, I tried add some code in unity3D. 1) Clear all socket connection. 2) Set all socket related variant to null. 3) manually call GC. Unfortunately, the issue is still here.